# Remove error message in js if onclick the button

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

How can i remove error message if onclick the radio button , i have two grouped button for gender male and female, if user did not select gender means i will show error, if select any one button that is male or female means it will remove error message, my code is below

---

```
<input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" id="gender">Male <input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" id="gender">Female <div id="gender_error"></div>
```

---

js validation code

```
var form_elements = document.getElementById('my_form').elements;
var gender = form_elements['gender'].value;
submit = true;
if(gender == '')
    {
        document.getElementById('gender_error').innerHTML = "Select Gender";
        submit = false;
    }
    return submit;
document.getElementById('gender').onclick = removewarning;
function removewarning()
{
    document.getElementById(this.id +'_error').innerHTML = "";
}
```

if user did not select gender means it will show error message select gender, but my problem is if user select male button then only the error message is removed, its not working for female button, anyone please help

Comment: You can't use a id twice. Try it with different ids.
For example:

var gender1 = form_elements['gender-1'].value;
var gender2 = form_elements['gender-2'].value;

Answer (score 0):

Change the below code:

```
document.getElementById('gender').onclick = removewarning;
```

to

```
document.getElementsByClassName('gender-button').onclick = removewarning;
```

and change the class name of button to `gender-button` or something you like.

Then I dont know which element have id `gender_error` but it seems you are writing your error message to that node so you can replace

`document.getElementById(this.id +'_error').innerHTML = "";`

with

`document.getElementById('gender_error').innerHTML = "";`